# client_max_body_size not working and leads to HTTP 413

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, vuejs2

When I upload a 2MB file to my web application the brother show a 413 HTTP status in response. But if I upload a 500KB file that works.

**Technologies :**

- Vuejs (2.6.14), Vuetify, Nuxt (2.15.8)
- Nginx 1.21.6
- SSL
- Docker (serveur 20.10.17)

**Analyse**
On Nginx conf I have set *client_max_body_size 20m;* but not working.
If I set the value to 30k and trie to upload the 500KB file I have a 413 HTTP status.
After some attemps I conclude that if the file is less than 1MB the upload works. But if the file is larger than 1MB there is a 413, even with this configuration in Nginx : *client_max_body_size 20m;*

**Something else**
If I limit to 30k and I try to upload a 500KB the error message is

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
nginx/1.21.6
```

If I limit to 30k and I try to upload a 2MB the error message is following
The version number disappears as if it were another server responding

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
nginx
```

If I limit to 20m and I try to upload a 2MB the error message is

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
nginx
```

**Conf nginx**

```
location ~ (/api|/mail-images|/swagger-ui|/v3/api-docs) {
        proxy_pass http://****;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cookie_path / "/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=none;";
        client_max_body_size 20M;
    }
```

I haved search on stackoverflow with *client_max_body_size* keyword and try solution proposed but without success.

Do you have any research leads?

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are always hitting the given location?
If that is yes - then the error is coming from the service you are proxying to, here: `proxy_pass http://****;`

You need to configure that server too, if it's NGINX too, the default `client_max_body_size` is `1M`.

Comment: I'm not sure @NikolayDimitrov. I put a different access_log /var/log/nginx/locationXXX.log main; on each location, server and http. If I send a 30KB file there is a log in error_log and in access_log of this above location. If I send a 2MB file, there is no log

Comment: Not sure about the logs, but I now reviewed your question and actually it's definitely different nginx server as you get different server header. Which means the second limitation is coming from the service your are proxying to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So according to you, with this information nginx 1.21.6 lets the request pass.

Comment: Yes, definitely that is the case.